# How do I attach a QRegexpValidator to QFileDialog if I only want say identifier file names?

Tags: qt5, pyqt5, qfiledialog, qvalidator

The question is pretty straightforward and in the title.

Googling didn't help on this one.  How do I get the QFileDialog to use a QValidator on its save name field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a bit of a kludge but appears to work.

You can use [`QObject::findChildren`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren) to locate the dialog's `QLineEdit` child widgets.  Assuming there's only one such widget you can then apply the validator to that...

```
QFileDialog fd;
auto children = fd.findChildren<QLineEdit *>();
if (children.size() == 1) {

  /*
   * Apply a validator that forces the user to enter a name
   * beginning with a lower case `a' -- a bit pointless but...
   */
  QRegExpValidator validator(QRegExp("^a"));

  /*
   * Apply the validator.
   */
  children.front()->setValidator(&validator);
  fd.exec();
}
```

A quick test suggests it appears to work just fine.  Like I said though: it does feel like a bit of a kludge.